# Why do localized sites present a non-english UI to users whose Accept-Language clearly says "english"?

Tags: support, localization

I'm not going to use a site where I don't speak the language but in case there was e.g. a German Stack Overflow I'd probably still prefer the English version of the site itself (and just the German content).

So I wonder if there's any reason why e.g. http://br.stackoverflow.com ignores this header? Or is it just a default and you can change the UI language after signing up? It might also be helpful the other way round: Someone who prefers using English resources but likes the UI in his native language.

Comment: I guess a strong case could be made for having only one language per international site. This is the first time they are starting a SO clone in a different language, and they may want to be able to tweak stuff without having to bother keeping an English translation (likely useless to most visitors) in sync.

Comment: But they probably use some translation system like gettext in which case they'd have the english strings available anyway

Comment: But what if you need entirely new elements, areas, categories...? Lots of changes may be needed, especially during the starting period, and updating English translations alongside may be bothersome.

Comment: I doubt there's a separate codebase - so if they add xyz to the localized page they'll add it to *all* pages, i.e. they need an english version anyway!

Comment: You may be right - I don't know the internals and how things are set up. Maybe it's really just the click of a button for them. But it's not *necessarily* that straightforward

Comment: Somebody somewhere would be cursing you right now for suggesting this :P

Answer (score 6):

A problem with relying too much on Accept-Language is that most people don't even realize that such a setting exists, much less how to change it.

At best, it may default to the language chosen when the OS and/or the browser was installed, which will *hopefully* be something the user at least vaguely understands — unless the user happens to be, say, using a public computer while traveling.  Also, many users who speak something other than English natively may still have English set as their OS / browser interface language, even though they only understand it just enough to navigate the UI.

Using Accept-Language as a *hint* for guessing the user's preferred language *may* be acceptable in some cases, but it *must* be accompanied by a mechanism for changing the language if the guess is wrong, and the mechanism must be robust and obvious enough to remain usable even if, in the worst case, the user doesn't understand the guessed language at all.

In practice, it's often easier and more reliable to ignore Accept-Language and other similar cues entirely, and just let the (default / only) interface language be the same as the content language.  If I'm looking for answers on SO em Português, I presumably understand at least a *little* bit of Portuguese, so it makes sense to show the interface in that language rather than try to guess *which* other language I might understand better.

(Thought experiment: if you went on a trip to China, and needed to visit SO from a local friend's computer there, would you like it if the interface was all in Chinese?  And how long do you think it would take you to figure out how to switch it back to English?)

See also: [How should I structure my URLs for both SEO and localization?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization) on webmasters.SE.

Comment: I'd like the site to show a notification bare that the site language is xyz and offer me a way to switch to <other language>

Comment: That would indeed be one good way to deal with the issue.